# OS X gets stuck at the login window and only displays the dark blue linen background

Tags: macos, osx-lion, updates, safe-mode, login-screen

I had to hard boot my MacBook off last night after it got stuck in a Keynote presentation.

On the restart, I opened Safari / Chrome and would visit a webpage and about a second after rendering the window would go white (clear on Chrome).

I did a proper restart, and it came back up to the grey screen before you can login. (Mouse active. Functions volume, brightness etc active.)

[image]

It was stuck there all night and occasionally it would flicker. I rebooted this morning into safe mode which worked fine. Rebooted and came to this screen again.

I'm not really sure what the next steps should be. I've never really had to troubleshoot my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to boot in to safe mode (as mentioned above) by holding shift as soon as the screen lit up until the apple log and timer/working gif showed up.

Logging in then I checked for a software update which was available. Installed/restarted.

I'm not sure that the update itself had a fix or if perhaps it reset some corrupted file/setting used in the boot sequence.

Either way. If you have this problem, try updating from safe mode.

Update: After being able to work on my computer again I noticed a "sticky" drag and drop issue. The mouse would drag icon's around/out of finder but would not drop them.

More research lead me to an issue with a recent update for "**Air Display**"

I did install that update a few weeks ago, but never rebooted. I believe the issue with Air Display and the **late 2008 macbook** was the source of the original problem and subsequent drag/drop issue.

Everything seems groovy now.